# What exactly does "CategoryName" "CounterName" and "InstanceName" mean?

Tags: c#

When you're using them to gain information on how much CPU is being used you have to use these objects (I think they're objects) but I'm not sure what they do?

For example:

```
    CategoryName = "Processor", 
    CounterName = "% Processor Time", 
    InstanceName = "_Total" };
```

Do these objects get information from the processor? What are these called and what are they used for?

Thanks

Comment: Term you're looking for is "Performance Counters": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx) class

In which case:

> CategoryName Gets or sets the name of the performance counter category for this performance counter.
>
> CounterName Gets or sets the name of the performance counter that is associated with this PerformanceCounter instance.
>
> InstanceName Gets or sets an instance name for this performance counter.

For each of those on the MSDN page you can drill into them for further detail

Comment: I read that page a little earlier but I didn't understand it 100%. With the following code: http://i.gyazo.com/2c6a6c17eaf726e7c8d9f14c9486ce48.png you can see them being used to find the percentage of the CPU being used.. but how are they used together. I don't understand what is meant by "Gets or sets the name of the performance counter category for this performance counter."  Also thanks for helping me.

Comment: Performance counters report back to the OS reporting (I'm blanking on the name). So setting something like the Category Name changes how it is grouped in the MMC snap in panel. If you look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.categoryname(v=vs.110).aspx and read the Remarks section, they will give you examples. That's for CategoryName. If you jump around the documentation to the other ones you asked about and read their remarks you will see similar examples

Comment: That link really clarifies it! Thanks again for your help Prescott.